# In which Scenario's we call refresh() on applicationContext and what is the difference between start() and refresh() method's?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Need to know the difference between start() and refresh() methods in  application context. Can we call start() instead of refresh() if we want to reload the applicationContext ???

Also how to reload a specific bean in application Context where some changes were done in that bean and want to reload that bean again...

Comment: @reloadable or something like that

Comment: I still havent get the rite answer In which scenario's we call refresh() method ?? Will that refresh() causes all beans to be reinitialized again ???